# How to change tag values with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have this wonderful iFrame that has wonkey dimensions that I want to change to something useful on load.

```
<iframe id="iWork" width="640px" height="530px" />
```

I've tried googling around and found that the following should work, but it does not seem to do anything:

```
var query = document.querySelector("#iWork");
if (query) {
    query.setAttribute("width", "1000");
    query.setAttribute("height", "1000");
}
```

... but it doesn't change anything :-/

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong would be awesome.

Comment: Can you show the full content of your Greasemonkey script?

Comment: Hey @RobW, I'm nowhere near my computer (on a tablet on the road), but the rest is simply the boilerplate greasemonkey comment section. I'll happily upload it when I get home if you think it can have an impact, of course, but I doubt it.

Comment: I have some thoughts about the cause of your problem. I have to see the full source code (including the meta block) before an answer can be given.

Comment: @RobW, sorry, I've been busy scalding my daughter :-s  Here's the full code: http://pastie.org/3710613

Comment: What about a page which includes the HTML? That's also important. http://jsfiddle.net/ can be used for this purpose.

Comment: @RobW, well it worked fine on jsfiddle, so I naturally tried another browser. Works as intended in Chrome! I don't know why my Firefox and Greasemonkey do not play nice with the site, but I'll just chug on in Chrome. Thanks for the site link! :)

Comment: Does the *User script* work in JSFiddle? I meant: Copy-paste the real, relevant code (including resources) from your site in the JSFiddle, so that I can verify that the user script is not working.

Comment: @RobW, I know - what I meant was that since the script worked in JSFiddle, I tested in another browser and it worked. It must therefore be an issue with my Firefox and Greasemonkey installation. If you're still interested, I'll gladly Share the ancient HTML it is running on, but since the source of my problems was my software I think you'll find it boring. Again, thanks for your time :-)

Comment: I think that `// @run-at document-end` might fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code works fine for me.

you can test it here:

- with GM: http://banrilab.dyndns.org/
- without GM: http://jsfiddle.net/sVG4E/

the GM script

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           TEST
// @namespace      TEST
// @description    TEST
// @include        http*://banrilab.dyndns.*
// ==/UserScript==

var query = document.querySelector("#iWork");
if (query) {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        query.setAttribute("width", "500");
        query.setAttribute("height", "500");
    }, 3000)
}
```

i just added a timeout so you can see the size change after 3 seconds

Comment: I found out that it works fine in Chrome, so it must be an issue with my local browser and Greasemonkey. Thank you for taking the time to test and post, though :)

Comment: @Jan No problem :) by the way, tested with `FF 11.0` and `GM 0.9.18`

Comment: Minor note: After finally upgrading to `FF11.0`, it works like a charm.

Comment: @Jan nice. now maybe you could mark it as the right answer :)